# Can I define trait's variable in class?

Tags: php, traits

When I call **$article->test()->uri('test-content')** function, this is show test-content in trait for uri variable but in article class uri variable is return as null. How can I define *uri* variable with this call?

**Traits/Query.php:**

```
trait Query
{
    protected $uri;
    protected $v = 'v1';

    public function uri($uri)
    {
        $this->uri = $uri;
        return $this;
    }
```

**Content/Article.php**

```
class Article extends Api 
{
    use Query;

    public $content;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function test() {
        $this->content = $this->v . ' - ' . $this->uri;
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
$article->test()->uri('test-content');
```

it's calling `$article->test()` first. So you haven't called `Query::uri()` yet to fill in the `$uri` variable. You need to reverse it:

```
$article->uri('test-content')->test();
```